# How to Implement Butterknife.Action in AndroidX?

Tags: androidx, butterknife

I am not able to use ButterKnife.Action in andoidx, can someone give any suugestions on how to use ButterKnife.Action in androidx?

classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:9.0.0-rc2'

implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0'

Comment: what's the point to use this useless library? if you use Kotlin findVieById() is no more needed and assigning click listeners much more convenient and useful

Answer (score 0):

If you migrate to AndroidX you must use:

in gradle

dependencies {

implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.0"

annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.0"

...}

in class when you have errors

if you use code like this:

- ButterKnife.apply(new View[]{ ivImageId,vgSubscribtionsId,vgSubscribersID},

  ```
              (view, value, index) -> view.setVisibility(value), View.INVISIBLE);
  ```

replace to this for work with AndroidX:

- butterknife.Action viewAction = (view, index) -> {

  ```
          view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

      };
      butterknife.ViewCollections.run(new View[]{ ivImageId,vgSubscribtionsId,vgSubscribersID} , viewAction );
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I used the version 10.2.1 of ButterKnife .
Follow these steps and the problem will be fixed.

//Step 1 : import this line

```
import butterknife.Action;
```

//Step 2 : in Scope Class

```
butterknife.Action viewAction = new Action() 
{

     @Override public void apply(@NonNull View view, int index) 
    {
    // do something.
    }

};
```

//Step 3 : ButterKnife.apply() in new version is deprecated . Replace to:

```
 butterknife.ViewCollections.run(listView , viewAction );
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android studio Flamingo and above version below code working for butterknife library.

1. add below code in build.gradle(:app) file

   ```
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
        options.fork = true
        options.forkOptions.jvmArgs += [
                '--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED',
                '--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED',
                '--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED',
                '--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED',
                '--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED',
                '--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED',
                '--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED',
                '--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED',
                '--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED',
                '--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm=ALL-UNNAMED',
        ]
    }
   ```
2. ```
     android {
       ...
       // Butterknife requires Java 8.
       compileOptions {
         sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
         targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       }
     }

     dependencies {
       implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.3'
       annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.3'
     }
   ```
3. To use Butter Knife in a library, add the plugin to your buildscript:

   ```
    buildscript {
      repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
      }
      dependencies {
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:10.2.3'
      }
    }
   ```
4. and then apply it in your module:

   ```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
    apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
   ```
5. Now make sure you use R2 instead of R inside all Butter Knife annotations.

   ```
    class ExampleActivity extends Activity {
      @BindView(R2.id.user) EditText username;
      @BindView(R2.id.pass) EditText password;
    ...
    }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

With `androidX`, you should use

```
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
```

and then do something like new `butterknife.Action<View>()`

Package name is now `butterknife` with a `'b'` whereas before if was with a `'B'`

I hope this will help ...

Comment: It's not the correct explanation and  previously the package name was also same